# Anti-aliasing in LWJGL 3

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, antialiasing, post-processing

I am trying to draw an anti-aliased square in LWJGL 3. I am only drawing 2D sprites and I'm not drawing textures. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18714693/3931785) answer to a similar question reveals that anti-aliasing in LWJGL must be achieved with post-processing, but does not actually give an example or any resources on how to do this. Below is an example of some code. [This is what is rendered on screen from the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTmYA.png) Please tell me how to modify this code to make anti-aliasing possible.

```
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;

import org.lwjgl.*;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.*;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.*;

public class LWJGLTest {

    private GLFWErrorCallback errorCallback;
    private GLFWKeyCallback   keyCallback;

    private long window;

    public void run() {

        try {
            init();
            loop();

            glfwDestroyWindow(window);
            keyCallback.release();
        } finally {

            glfwTerminate();
            errorCallback.release();
        }
    }

    int WIDTH = 300;
    int HEIGHT = 300;

    private void init() {

        glfwSetErrorCallback(errorCallback = GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err));

        if ( glfwInit() != GLFW_TRUE )
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");

        glfwDefaultWindowHints();
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE);

        window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Hello World!", NULL, NULL);
        if ( window == NULL )
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");

        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallback = new GLFWKeyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void invoke(long window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
                if ( key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE )
                    glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GLFW_TRUE);
            }
        });

        GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());

        glfwSetWindowPos(
            window,
            (vidmode.width() - WIDTH) / 2,
            (vidmode.height() - HEIGHT) / 2
        );

        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        glfwSwapInterval(1);

        glfwShowWindow(window);
    }

    private void loop() {
        GL.createCapabilities();

        glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        while ( glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == GLFW_FALSE ) {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            draw();

            glfwSwapBuffers(window);

            glfwPollEvents();
        }
    }

    private static void draw(){

        int vertices = 4;
        int colorSize = 3;
        int vertexSize = 3;

        FloatBuffer cBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertices * colorSize);
        cBuffer.put(0).put(0).put(0);
        cBuffer.put(0).put(0).put(0);
        cBuffer.put(0).put(0).put(0);
        cBuffer.put(0).put(0).put(0);
        cBuffer.flip();

        FloatBuffer vBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertices * vertexSize);
        vBuffer.put(0.4056f).put(0.5792f).put(0.0f);
        vBuffer.put(-0.5792f).put(0.4056f).put(0.0f);
        vBuffer.put(-0.4056f).put(-0.5792f).put(0.0f);
        vBuffer.put(0.5792f).put(-0.4056f).put(0.0f);
        vBuffer.flip();



        IntBuffer ib = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(2);

        glGenBuffers(ib);

        int vHandle = ib.get(0);
        int cHandle = ib.get(1);

        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vHandle);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexPointer(vertexSize, GL_FLOAT, vertexSize*4, 0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cHandle);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glColorPointer(colorSize, GL_FLOAT, colorSize*4, 0);

        glDrawArrays(GL_POLYGON, 0, vertices);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        ib.put(0, vHandle);
        ib.put(1, cHandle);
        glDeleteBuffers(ib);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        new LWJGLTest().run();

    }

}
```

Comment: "This answer to a similar question reveals that anti-aliasing in LWJGL must be achieved with post-processing" It says no such thing. It *used* to say that until someone who actually know what they were talking about removed that nonsense.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ah yes, I see. In my research, I have unearthed a [java-gaming.org thread](http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/lwjgl-antialiased-lines/30894/msg/285878/view.html#msg285878) about multisampling and have had trouble adapting it to my code. I will try harder :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable **multisampling (MSAA)** in GLFW which should give you the effect you want. Look up using **GL_SAMPLES** on it.

e.g.

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_STENCIL_BITS, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
```

before you create the window.