# Is there any way to make drawn small objects in OpenGL in Java not so jagged?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm trying to smooth the edges of a rendered object. It looks like this:

[image]

The edges of this object are not smooth.

This object is drawn in game overlay using method that uses custom renderer and framebuffers: [WorldRenderer](https://github.com/ZeroedInOnTech/1.8.8/blob/master/1.8.8/Build%20918/src/minecraft/net/minecraft/client/renderer/WorldRenderer.java) and [Tesselator](https://github.com/ZeroedInOnTech/1.8.8/blob/master/1.8.8/Build%20918/src/minecraft/net/minecraft/client/renderer/Tessellator.java), but I don't know if having this knowledge is needed for answering this question.

I have tried adding this lines of code, but it didn't work:

```
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
GL11.glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Drawing object method:

```
    public static void drawCircle(final double x, final double y, final double r, final int c) {
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        glHint(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);
        GLUtils.glColor(c);

        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 360; i++) {
            final double x2 = Math.sin(((i * Math.PI) / 180)) * r;
            final double y2 = Math.cos(((i * Math.PI) / 180)) * r;
            glVertex3d(x + x2, y + y2, 0);
        }

        glEnd();

        glDisable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
```

I also noticed that if I render rectangle or something else behind the object (in same method, not from seperate classes), the edges aren't pixelated, but I want to smooth edges without doing it:
[image]

If you need something more, let me know.
Thank you very much for help.

Comment: Does this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702467/enable-anti-aliasing-with-lwjgl

Comment: I saw it before and it doesn't help me :(